# Using Bootstrap 4 to display email input validation messages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrap-4

Below I have attempted to utilise HTML 5 validation along with [custom styles from the Bootstrap 4 form page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/?#custom-styles) to display error messages below each field.

The default custom styles technique in Bootstrap doesn't seem to allow for any mechanism to update the error messages, specifically with the error messages that HTML 5 now supplies for email input fields. I have rolled my own Javascript to do this.

Is there a more appropriate Bootstrappy way to do this?

```js
  $( "#needs-validation" ).submit(function( event ) {
     if (this.checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
     }
     this.classList.add('was-validated');
  });

  // Email validation.
  $( "#email" ).change(function() {
     var email = $(this);
     if (email.is(':invalid')) {
        email.removeClass('is-valid').addClass('is-invalid');
        email.siblings(".invalid-feedback").text(email.prop("validationMessage"))
     } else {
        email.removeClass('is-invalid').addClass('is-valid');
     }
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




<form class="container" id="needs-validation" novalidate>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom03">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="email address" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide a valid email.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom04">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom04" placeholder="Name" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide a valid name.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You should use the built in validation API in modern browsers. [Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api)'s information about them. The docs for Bootstrap client side validation can be found [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/?#validation).

Comment: Hi @Klooven. I am using the HTML 5 validation API. Note in my example that I am not performing the validation. I am only checking if HTML 5 has marked the field as being invalid, and if it has, I am displaying the message in the `DIV.invalid-feedback` field that Bootstrap uses for displaying validation messages (because I don't see a way to get Bootstrap to change the validation message).